# Using Sales Order TR order type in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

We have exposed CustomerID and Customer Location for TR order type, as standard Acumatica will not expose these fields. We have another custom screen which will be created before we create a shipment, so our custom screen will store these customer and customer location details for another purpose.

We are unable to create a shipment with the customer of type customer and vendor, it is allowing to create shipment only with company type customer. This is working in 2017R2 but not in 2019R1.

Here is the error message:

> An error occurred during processing of the field Customer value C000000001 AR Error: Incorrect value specified. Specify a customer (for shipments of the Shipment type) or a company business account (for shipments of the Transfer type).

Sample code to make fields visible for TR Order Type also. I am trying this is fresh Acumatica instance with Sales data and without customizations published.

```
protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;

   if (row.OrderType == "TR")
        {
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<SOOrder.customerID>(cache, (object)row, true);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<SOOrder.customerLocationID>(cache, (object)row, true);
          }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: Hi Samvel, i have updated sample code in question, please have a look.

Comment: Can you please explain why do you want to use Transfer Orders with some customers? Transfer Orders are designed for working in the inner scope of the company and not between the company and the customer or the vendor.

Comment: If you want to add some customer/vendor tracking to transfer order I would suggest adding separate fields.